# Array elementwise operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, elementwise-operations

I have two input arrays x and y of the same shape.  I need to run each of their elements with matching indices through a function, then store the result at those indices in a third array z.  What is the most pythonic way to accomplish this?  Right now I have four four loops - I'm sure there is an easier way.

```
x = [[2, 2, 2],
     [2, 2, 2],
     [2, 2, 2]]

y = [[3, 3, 3],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [3, 3, 1]]

def elementwise_function(element_1,element_2):
    return (element_1 + element_2)

z = [[5, 5, 5],
     [5, 5, 5],
     [5, 5, 3]]
```

I am getting confused since my function will only work on individual data pairs.  I can't simply pass the x and y arrays to the function.

Comment: numpy arrays are element wise by default. That is, x+y=z

Comment: Is there any hope that you can do the operation on the matrix level? For example, `z = x + y` works in your example above. Perhaps you could show us what your function is and we can help you get it working on matrices?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One "easier way" is to create a NumPy-aware function using [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). A "ufunc" is NumPy terminology for an elementwise function (see documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)). Using `numpy.vectorize` lets you use your element-by-element function to create your own ufunc, which works the same way as other NumPy ufuncs (like standard addition, etc.): the ufunc will accept arrays and it will apply your function to each pair of elements, it will do array shape broadcasting just like standard NumPy functions, etc. The [documentation page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) has some usage examples that might be helpful.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: def myfunc(a, b):
   ...:     "Return 1 if a>b, otherwise return 0"
   ...:     if a > b:
   ...:         return 1
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return 0
   ...: vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
   ...: 

In [2]: vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1])
   ...: 
Out[2]: array([0, 0, 1, 1])
In [3]: vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
   ...: 
Out[3]: array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 4):

(I'm guessing your talking about simple python `list`, not `numpy.array`)

Recursion always making our life easier:

```
def operate_on_Narray(A, B, function):
    try:
        return [operate_on_Narray(a, b, function) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
    except TypeError as e:
        # Not iterable
        return function(A, B)
```

Usage:

```
>>> x = [[2, 2, 2],
...      [2, 2, 2],
...      [2, 2, 2]]
>>> 
>>> y = [[3, 3, 3],
...      [3, 3, 3],
...      [3, 3, 1]]
>>> operate_on_Narray(x, y, lambda a, b: a+b)
[[5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 3]]
```

It will work in any other kind of dimensional array:

```
>>> operate_on_Narray([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], lambda a, b: a*b)
[4, 10, 18]
```

Answer (score 3):

The following transcript from a python 2.7.3 interpreter session illustrates use of builtin function `map` to apply an elementwise operation to 2D-matrix elements.  (Note: `operator.add` is equivalent to the `elementwise_function` specified in question, and also equivalent to the lambda expression in the second use of `applier`.)

```
>>> import operator
>>> def applier(a, b, op):
...     return map(lambda ro: map(op, ro[0], ro[1]), zip(a,b))
... 
>>> applier(x, y, operator.add)
[[5, 5, 2], [5, 4, 5], [6, 5, 5]]
>>> x; y
[[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2]]
[[3, 3, 1], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> applier(x, y, lambda p,q: p+q)
[[5, 5, 2], [5, 4, 5], [6, 5, 5]]
>>> applier(x, y, lambda p,q: p-q)
[[-1, -1, 0], [-1, 0, -1], [0, -1, -1]]
>>> applier(x, y, lambda p,q: p*q)
[[6, 6, 1], [6, 4, 6], [9, 6, 6]]
```

Note, the above has x, y as follows:

```
x=[[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2]]
y=[[3, 3, 1], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

As mentioned before, the transcript above is from  a python 2.7.3 interpreter session.  If this code is run in python 3, it will instead return map objects.  One can use a function like the following to see the numbers:

```
def itemize(m):
    return [itemize(e) for e in m] if hasattr(m, '__iter__') else m
```

With that function in place, the statement

```
itemize(applier(x, y, operator.add))
```

returns

```
[[5, 5, 2], [5, 4, 5], [6, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: This method returns "<map object at 0x10eebc438>"

Comment: @onurcanbektas, that's a consequence of python 3 vs 2.  See edit for more info and of course upvote the edit!